# Why might MS Outlook 2010 (under WIN7) have stopped loading at "Loading Profile"?

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail

MS Outlook 2010, set as a front end to 2 GMAIL accounts (all under WIN7) stops loading at "Loading Profile".
It occurred first after a hung transfer of large files between the gmail accounts.

I've tried opening Outlook in safe mode, rebooted and tried again in safe mode, run the MS Office Repair function using the original MS Office Pro (32 bit) installation disk, and also deleted recent installations of unrelated programs.

Also seen the similar 2014 question from Barbara, and found the recommended Microsoft Office Configuration Analyzer Tool 1.2 microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36852 is no longer available.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Uninstall Office 2010, restart the computer, and install Office 2010 again and patch. There are patches in 2020 for Office 2010 running in Windows 7.

Comment: Uninstall hung; trying recent restore point prior to the problem,

Comment: Your Windows 7 system is at fault. I hope you have the Windows 7 install media.  If you do, try a Windows 7 Repair Install.  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: Instead of uninstall, try in *Control Panel > Programs and Features* to right-click Office and select Change to repair.

Comment: I tried switching Uninstall to Change, but it tells me to wait till Uninstall is finished...

Comment: John, I may well have to reinstall Windows but preferably as the last resort. Thanks

Comment: Please try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Aidan, John, @Harrymc - Thanks to all for replies. Problem eventually solved after - luckily - a partial restore appeared (after many attempts) and then a friend suggested then using Softpedia's MS Office Suite Removal tool, which reached Registry Fix stage, then the Registry Cleaner in C-Cleaner, and after checking MS Office suite was expunged completely, doing a full reinstall from the original disk, and some fiddling around to get to the product key input.

Comment: John, Just to acknowledge that your initial advice was the correct answer, but other problems prevented its implementation. Whether or not there is a problem with my installation of Win7 I didn't discover, but am satisfied with the current status as I greatly prefer to avoid having to reinstall all my other applications , gien that some of the disks aren't easily available. Again thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 18-06-2020
A recurrence, though possibly a slight variation of the original problem - MS OUTLOOK appeared again to hang at “Loading Profile” after closing down hurriedly. Although restarting in Safe Mode seemed unhelpful, I left it for a while after closing down most of the open applications, and later found it trying to resynchronise folder. In spite of a couple of Send/Receive Error messages, it seems to have sorted itself out. I should add that it's front-ending a nearly full gmail account, with two linked gmail addresses, totaling about 14GB of emails plus some linked .PST files. So it takes a while to resync...

ORIGINAL POST
MS Outlook 2010 (under WIN7) stopped loading at “Loading Profile” *seemingly*, as it couldn't verify the product key.

However, ***the problem arose after a transfer***, between two gmail accounts, of about 25 emails in MS OUTLOOK (which front ended the gmail accounts) with a total of ~300MB of attachments, ***crashed***.

Thereafter, MS Outlook wouldn't load beyond the "Loading Profile" sign and the MS Office Suite as a whole could neither be uninstalled nor overwritten.

Had I first known it when MS Office had ceased to function correctly, the easiest solution (instead of repeatedly and ineffectually trying to do a system restore from MS Backup & Restore) might well have been then immediately to:

- download a free copy of Softpedia's MS Office Suite Removal tool, https://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Uninstallers/Microsoft-Office-Suite-Removal-Tool.shtml#download and allow it to run till it reached at least the Registry Fix stage,
- then use the Registry Cleaner in C-Cleaner (free download: https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/windows-update ),
- checking MS Office suite was expunged completely,
- rebooting,
- and then doing a full reinstall from the original disk,
- and maybe some fiddling around to get to the product key input dialogue box.

I hope this answer will save someone else from having to work through most of the night and, after little sleep, waking to fears of a full Windows reinstall and mislaid application disks...